# how to pass input text type value to java script function | ionic v1

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

Failed to pass value of input type text to my javascript function
I read questions regarding about it but I'm at ionic framework v1 and I can't add javascript after loading my code is

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <ion-list ng-repeat="home in items">
      <ion-checkbox ng-model="home.status">
        {{home.item}}
      </ion-checkbox>
    </ion-list>
    <div class="bar bar-footer item-input-inset">
      <label for="" class="item-input-wrapper">
        <input name="homeNewItem" type="text" placeholder="New Home ToDo">
      </label>
      <button class="button button-small button-balanced" type="submit" ng-click="add(document.getElementByName('homeNewItem').value)">Add</button>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and Errors are that undefined value is passed when reaching javascript method
[image: undefined at last is value]
 undefined at last is value that i get

here is my javaScript Code

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.add = function(data){

    console.log("add function called "+data)
    var temp = {
      item : data,
      status : false
    };

    $scope.items.push(temp);
  };
  $scope.items=[
    {
      item : "Repair TV",
      status : false,
    },
    {
      item : "Do Nothing",
      status : true,
    },
  ];
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited code.

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <ion-list ng-repeat="home in items">
      <ion-checkbox ng-model="home.status">
        {{home.item}}
      </ion-checkbox>
    </ion-list>
    <div class="bar bar-footer item-input-inset">
      <label for="" class="item-input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" placeholder="New Home ToDo" ng-model="name">
      </label>
      <button class="button button-small button-balanced"  ng-click="add(name)">Add</button>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Javascript code

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name;
  $scope.add = function(data){
    console.log("add function called "+data)
    var temp = {
      item : data,
      status : false
    };

    $scope.items.push(temp);
  };
  $scope.items=[
    {
      item : "Repair TV",
      status : false,
    },
    {
      item : "Do Nothing",
      status : true,
    },
  ];
})
```

Comment: these two files are not connected to each other I'm using ionic framework

Comment: Instead of passing via function, i am calling on click using id. both are same.

Comment: Yup this one works. Thanks I already figured it out and post my answer also.

Answer (score 0):

This code needs some modification. As ionic is build in AngularJS so you can use ng-model directive and refer that variable to JavaScript Method when needed. here is one solution that I figure out

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <ion-list ng-repeat="home in items">
      <ion-checkbox ng-model="home.status">
        {{home.item}}
      </ion-checkbox>
    </ion-list>
    <div class="bar bar-footer item-input-inset">
      <label for="" class="item-input-wrapper">
        <input id="homeNewItem" type="text" placeholder="New Home ToDo" ng-model(value)>
      </label>
      <button class="button button-small button-balanced"  ng-click="add(value)">Add</button>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

JavaScript is fine.